# Calculating Volume: how to find Z when it's given inside a range e.g. $x^2+y^2\leq z \leq 4$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm having trouble with these questions, mainly because I don't know how to find the Z function when it's inside a range.

Calculate the volume of:

a) $x^2+y^2\le z \le 4$
(answer: $48\pi$)

b) $x^2+y^2\le4 , x^2+y^2+z^2\le9$  (answer $\frac{(\pi)}{4}\times(e^4-e)$)

For a) I tried the following:

I converted to polar coordinates

$x^2+y^2=r^2$

$r^2\le4, 0\le r\le2$

$0\le\theta\le2\pi$

For the Z function (height) I considered it as: $4-r^2$ since $x^2+y^2\le z\le4$

So I got this integral for the volume: $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2(4-r^2)rdrd\theta = 8\pi$$ which is not even close to $48\pi$

I also tried b) but got it wrong as well.

Comment: For (a), $48\pi$ is even larger than the enclosing cylinder $x^2+y^2\le 4$, $0\le z \le 4$...

Comment: Yeah, $48\pi$ felt like too much, but that's the answer... maybe my teacher mixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might misunderstand the problem.

For (a), as mentioned in the comment, the answer looks wrong.

$x^2+y^2\le z\le 4$

It is a 3-D shape. When $z$ = 1, the circle you have to consider is $x^2+y^2 = 1$ and the inside area.

In other words, as $z$ changes the radius of the circle changes also.

Therefore the right integral should be
$$ \int ^4_0 \int^\sqrt{z}_0 \int^{2\pi}_0 r d\theta dr dz = 8\pi$$

Comment: I thought it is a cone. But it is not. The radius of the circle is not $z$ but $\sqrt{z}$.

Comment: Please can you tell me how it would like using double integrals? I'm curious to know how the integrand and bounds would look like.

I'm asking because on my answer I somehow got $8\pi$ as well, was that just pure luck or related to a double integral resolution?

Comment: Step by step 
$$ \int ^4_0 \left[\int^\sqrt{z}_0 \left[ \int^{2\pi}_0 r d\theta \right] dr \right] dz $$ 
$$= \int ^4_0 \left[\int^\sqrt{z}_0 ( 2\pi r) dr \right] dz$$
$$= \int ^4_0 \left[\pi r^2\right]^{\sqrt{z}}_0  dz$$
$$= \int^4_0 \pi z dz = 8\pi$$